# How to validate Zipcode using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Am using this validation plugin

https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine

Already it is having zip code validation.However, I want to update zipcode validation as below:

Zip code should be 6 or 9 digits in the following format xxxxxx or xxxxx-xxxx. If user enters either 6 or 9 digits in the above format then it should validate. If user enters other than 6 or 9 digits not in the above format it should not allow.

Comment: So, can you show us what have you tried? Programming is also about thinking

Comment: Am using this regex. However, its not validating correctly.."regex": "/^[0-9]{6}|[0-9]{5}-[0-9]{4}$/",

Answer (score 0):

In `/ js / languages / jquery.validationEngine-en.js`

add a rule:

```
"zip": {
    "regex": "/^[0-9]{6}|[0-9]{5}-[0-9]{4}$/",
    "alertText": "Enter Valid Zip Code (XXXXXX or XXXXX-XXXX)"
},
```

Now you can include in your html:

```
<input type="text" class="validate[custom[zip]]">
```

Comment: it is not validating correctly..even if i follow the format it shows error

Comment: Can you put this online somewhere?